# Capitalize first letter of Url using Routing in .net MVC (Url Routing to UpperCase)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I want to make first letter capital from my Url

```
this is what I have:
http://www.example.com/test/testing-url

this is what I want:
http://www.example.com/Test/Testing-Url
```

Is it possible to do this in .net MVC Routing and if yes then how can I achieve this?

What I tried for this is I did a Regex expression use in Application_BeginRequest in `global.asax` but it's not working.

Comment: interesting, but why do you want to do this? What purpose does it have? I can't see an obvious advantage. In fact, in some ways having everything in lower-case is simpler and easier to work with. People don't usually care much about grammar in their URLs, either.

Comment: we have pattern like this in our Urls: `http://www.example.com/Test/Testing-Url`
but now what happens is if anyone enter url like `http://www.example.com/test/testing-url` then it becomes duplicate for SEO. so that's why we need to change it.

Comment: Ok. I don't know enough about SEO to say if that's a big problem or not, but anyway, it sounds like what you want could probably be achieved simply enough using an IIS rewrite rule, rather than routing configuration. Have you looked into that?

Answer (score -1):

You can use  the npm module named as "lodash".
It converts the first character of string to upper case and the remaining to lower case.At first require it using the command:
`const _ = require('lodash');`

Arguments:
**[string=''] (string): The string to capitalize.**

Returns:
**(string): Returns the capitalized string.**

For example,
`_.capitalize('FRED');`
`// => 'Fred'`

Or If you are not satisfied with my solution refer:https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#capitalize

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).